# How can I filter 2 arrays with 2 input field react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, map-function

I want to filter the data based on name and tag using 2 input fields. with the name it is filtering fine but how can I filter by tags.tagList and I am trying hard but didn't get any solution. I want to show data if someone search by name then they can show the data. Also in they can search data by tag but tag list in another array. how can solve this?

```
const Home = () => {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([{ idNumber: "", tagList: "" }]);
  const [searchByName, setSearchByName] = useState("");
  const [searchByTag, setSearchByTag] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = ".../students";
    fetch(url)
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => setStudents(data.students));
  }, []);

  const addTags = (id, tag, keyCode) => {
    if (keyCode == 13) {
      const newTag = [...tags, { idNumber: id, tagList: tag }];
      setTags(newTag);
      `document.getElementById(`tags${id}`).value = "";`
    }
  };
```

```
  return (
    <main className="student-container">
      <div className="search-box">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search by name..."
          onChange={(e) => setSearchByName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="search-box">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search by tag..."
          onChange={(e) => setSearchByTag(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>

      {students.map((student) => {
        if (searchByName.length !== 0) {
          if (
            `${student.firstName} ${student.lastName}`
              .toLocaleLowerCase()
              .startsWith(searchByName.toLocaleLowerCase())
          ) {
            return (
              <StudentCard
                key={student.id}
                student={student}
                addTags={addTags}
                tags={tags}
              />
            );
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        }
        return (
          <StudentCard
            key={student.id}
            student={student}
            addTags={addTags}
            tags={tags}
          />
        );
      })}
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Does each student have a list of tags ? i.e `idNumber` = `student.id` ?

Comment: No student didn't have any tag. Tags are in another array.

Comment: How do you want to filter students with tags? Does the `idNumber` property in the tags array is same as `student.id` that added the tags  ?

Comment: No, I want to show the data based on, what get typed in input fields. There will 2 input fields one for searching by name and another for searching by tag name. Tag name are getting added from in one array. in tags array there are 2 property, one idNumber, another tagList. In student array there are property called id, fristName, lastName and so on. But tag getting added based on student id.

Comment: Okay i wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67747806/5790722). Comment to the answer if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

You want a map like object for `tags` to easily look up `tagsList` of a specific user while filtering like below.

```
{ 
  id1: {id: id1, tagsList: [...]},
  id2: {id: id2, tagsList: [...]},
  id3: {id: id3, tagsList: [...]},
}
```

Here is a sample solution that can help. `tagsMap` is the above mentioned lookup object.

```js
const students = [
  { id: 1, firstName: "AB", lastName: "CD" },
  { id: 2, firstName: "CD", lastName: "EF" },
  { id: 3, firstName: "EF", lastName: "GH" },
];
const tagsList = [
  { idNumber: 1, tagsList: ["TA", "TB", "TC"] },
  { idNumber: 2, tagsList: ["TC", "TD"] },
  { idNumber: 3, tagsList: ["TD", "TE"] },
];

const searchByName = "C";
const searchByTag = "TD";

const tagsMap = tagsList.reduce((acc, tag) => {
  acc[tag.idNumber] = tag;
  return acc;
}, {});

const studentNameMatches = (student, searchTerm) =>
  `${student.firstName} ${student.lastName}`
    .toLocaleLowerCase()
    .startsWith(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase());

const studentHasTag = (student, tagName) =>
  tagsMap[student.id]?.tagsList.includes(tagName);

const filteredStudents = students.filter(
  (student) =>
    studentNameMatches(student, searchByName) &&
    studentHasTag(student, searchByTag)
);

// Students with name starting with "C" And has tag "TD"
console.log(filteredStudents);
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But this code is not okay for my condition.